# Extract subfolfders in a Path column inside a DataFrame

Tags: python

I have a dataframe that contains informations about directories : [Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bz7A.png)

```
    Path                                        |CreationDate   |ModificationDate
------------------------------------------------|---------------|-------------------
\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\dir6\file1            |2021-01-01     |2021-01-01
\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\file1                 |2021-01-02     |2021-01-03
\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\file2                 |2021-01-01     |2021-01-01
\dir10\dir11\dir12\dir13\dir14\dir15\dir16\file1|2021-01-04     |2021-01-05
```

In column first5Directory below, my expected results : I try to parse the Path column to extract the first 5 subfolders :
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P07HX.png)

```
    Path                                        |CreationDate   |ModificationDate   |first5Directory
------------------------------------------------|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------
\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\dir6\file1            |2021-01-01     |2021-01-01         |\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5
\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\file1                 |2021-01-02     |2021-01-03         |\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5
\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\file2                 |2021-01-01     |2021-01-01         |\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\
\dir10\dir11\dir12\dir13\dir14\dir15\dir16\file1|2021-01-04     |2021-01-05         |\dir10\dir11\dir12\dir13\dir14\
```

I try to split path column by '\' caracters, extract the 5 first items :

```
df['first5Directory'] = list(map(lambda x : x.split('\\'), df['Path']))
df['first5Directory'] = list(map(lambda x : x[1:6], df['first5Directory']))
```

I obtain this results :

```
first5Directory                                 
-------------------------------------------------
['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3', 'dir4', 'dir5']        
['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3', 'dir4', 'dir5']        
['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3', 'dir4', 'dir5']    
['dir10', 'dir11', 'dir12', 'dir13', 'dir14']
```

Then, I don't have idea to transform it to obtain my expected results.

Anyone can help me?
Regards.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. Are you trying to load all the data from five different directories for each row?

Comment: I'm sorry if it's not clear. The directories are sample of data inside a column in a csv file. I just want to extract all the caracter string from the left side of the fith '\'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to truncate each path to the first five subdirectories. Assuming each path has at least five, you can do that with something like this:

```
import os
df['Path'].str.split('\\').apply(lambda x: os.path.join(x[1:6]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I confirme you unterstood my problem.

Comment: I applied your solution but it doesn't work => TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list.
I think by applying the split function, the type of the object was changed to list and the os.path.join seems not supporte this type

Comment: `os.path.join` only takes a list. Maybe try `df['Path'].apply(lambda x: os.path.join(os.path.split(x)[1:6]))`?

Comment: use --->   df['Path'].apply(lambda x: os.path.dirname(x))

Comment: @Mose Wintner : I just tried it but without success. I have this error message => expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Comment: @Ade_1: Thanks for your answer. I don't have error when I applied your solution but it does not respond to my expected results. I just want the first five subdirectories in my path column. With your solution, I obtain all the directories part.

Comment: @Mose Wintner : Thanks for your help. I solved my problem with your first answer which I corrected. Here the solution : df['Path'].str.split('\\').apply(lambda x: os.path.join(*x[1:6]))

Answer (score 0):

use the ''.join method to finalise your as your last step by converting the list to a path

```
df['first5Directory'] = list(map(lambda x : x.split('\\'), df['Path']))
df['first5Directory'] = list(map(lambda x : x[1:6], df['first5Directory']))
# final step to your earlier function
df['first5Directory'].apply(lambda x : '\\'.joint(x) )
```

Comment: Thanks Ade_1. Your solution work too. I just make a little correction. Just add a second backslah : '\\'.join(x)